# How to generate sequence diagram from xmi file

Tags: java, xmi

Please help me
if any have ans for this question.

Thanks
Prashant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can generate xmi file for sequence diagram and it's very easy to implement it
just check below link, you can get all idea.

http://www.umlgraph.org/

Comment: The link seems to direct to an inappropriate site.

Answer (score 2):

This question does not make sense as such. XMI is a storage format for UML (and as pointed out above for any MOF-based language) models. Therefore a XMI file will contain the class diagram, sequence diagram, ... of your UML project.

Therefore, any tool able to load such UML diagram will be able to show the sequence diagram contained in it.

What may happen though is that the XMI file does not include the graphical layout information of your diagrams. So, you may import the model information but the tool may not display them graphically. You may need to browse the model, and one by one, take the model elements and reposition them in the canvas.

Comment: I want to create sequence diagram by generating xmi file. but when i that file importing agroUML software they can't display output. Why?

Comment: Read again the last paragraph of my post. Probably ArgoUML is importing the information on the model but it is not displaying. Create a new empty sequence diagram and try to drag and drop the elements from the left tree model browser to the new canvas

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the XMI file represents a sequence diagram, then you need to find a UML tool that reads XMI files, load the file and then send the file to the printer.

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools) includes a list of UML tools that are XMI capable.

If the XMI file is for some other kind of UML diagram, or something that is not UML at all<sup>*</sup>, then the simple answer is that you can't do it.

<sup>* It is a little known fact that the OMG XMI specification actually defines an XML serialization for *any modeling language* that has a OMG MOF-based metamodel.  XMI/UML is just one example.</sup>

Comment: I am using AgroUML tools. and also create one sequece diagram file in agrouml and than export as a xmi file and than that file i want to import, but not generate sequence diagram, why? i don't know. if you know so pls tell me

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying that you don't know how to create a sequence diagram in ArgoUML?  Are you saying that you don't know how to export it?  Are you saying that you don't know how to import it?

Comment: No dear i know how to draw sequence diagram, and also know how to export xmi file.

Comment: But main problem is whatever file we export and again that file we import in agrouml it will not generate sequence diagram, how???

Comment: I still cannot understand what you are saying.  But I must also admit that I just tried to create a sequence diagram using ArgoUML and could not figure out how to get the editor interface to work.

Comment: Yes i do that and i done that task. I think u can't getting what i am saying, thanks for spoiling your time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with Jordi. An XMI document describes a model. 
A model is different from its representation (diagrams) which could however be a model too aimed at describing the way elements belonging to the first model should be depicted. 
In TopCased for instance, a CASE tool based on the Eclipse Modeling Framework, a diagram is a model itself. So you could, and I actually did it thus it is possible, look at how TopCased describes diagrams in XMI and try to generate it from the XMI of your models.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Part of the confusion here is that UML 1 XMI did not contain diagram layout information, while UML 2 XMI can contain diagram layout information. So UML 2 XMI is both model and presentation (merits of this are debatable, but it eases portability).